# How to set language in text area in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, locale, jtextarea

I need to change the default language into Hebrew in all the text areas in the app. I tried to use Set Local, but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: *"Any idea?"* Post a [mre] showing what you did. It should only require one text area, and maybe 30 lines of code in total.

Comment: What does “set the default language” mean?  Do you want to set the input method?  For that, you can try calling each text area’s [getInputContext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#getInputContext()) method, and then calling the returned context’s [selectInputMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/im/InputContext.html#selectInputMethod(java.util.Locale)) method.  Be aware that some systems use a single global input method for the whole desktop, so changing it might come across as malicious.

Answer (score 2):

The below code demonstrates the only way I know of to configure a `JTextComponent` (which `JTextArea` is a subclass of) so that when it gains input focus it displays Hebrew characters. In other words no need for the user to explicitly change the language after the `JTextComponent` has gained focus and before the user starts entering text.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.im.InputContext;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class DfltHbrw implements ActionListener, FocusListener, Runnable {
    private static final Locale  HEBREW = new Locale("iw", "IL");
    private static final String  EXIT = "\u05E1\u05D2\u05D5\u05E8";

    private JFrame  frame;
    private JTextArea  textArea;

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionEvent
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        if (EXIT.equals(actionCommand)) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.FocusListener
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent event) {
        InputContext ic = textArea.getInputContext();
        ic.selectInputMethod(HEBREW);
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.FocusListener
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent event) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createButtons() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton(EXIT);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(button);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createTextArea() {
        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 60);
        textArea.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        textArea.addFocusListener(this);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Hebrew");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtons(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Start here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new DfltHbrw());
    }
}
```

I only added the `JButton` so that there would be more than one [GUI] component so as to allow transferring focus from one component to another.

The relevant part of the above code is the `focusGained()` method. I added a *focus listener* to the `JTextArea` which calls that method when the `JTextArea` gains focus. In fact the `focusGained()` method does the actual work of configuring the `JTextArea` for displaying Hebrew when the user starts to enter text into it.

Note that the same `focusGained()` method can be used to configure the `JTextArea` to display any [supported] language. All you need to change is the `Locale` argument that is passed to the `selectInputMethod()` method.

Also note that I only set the `ComponentOrientation` so that the Hebrew text in the `JTextArea` would look "natural". It is not required in order to configure the `JTextArea` for displaying Hebrew.